# Show/Hide Div in Web Application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a label in a div which I want to show or hide depending on the value of another text box the JavaScript function is written and working but in the ASP.NET code behind I use a select case statement to set the `DIVid.Visible` to `True` or `False` on the page load.

The javascript function for hiding the div only works when on the load it the DIVid.Visible is true the other parts of the JS function (disable a text box) work fine.

Is it something to do with because it can't find the DIVid because visible is false and how would I overcome this?

Comment: show your html and css?

Answer (score 2):

When you say `DIVid.Visible = false` in ASP.NET, that control is not rendered  so you won't be able to manipulate it using Javascript.

If for some reason, you want to handle the visibility at server side then you can add attributes like this:-

```
DIVid.Attributes.Add("style","display:none;");
```

Answer (score 2):

Set div style attribute not .net control visibility property.

```
yourDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none;");
```

Comment: @Rahul Singh did not see your answer, should I delete mine?

Comment: No need, your answer was not formatted so I just formatted that :D